# How to get Product Custom Image attribute Iabel?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have created one Custom Attribute of media image type.

> Attribute name = product_image_custom_1.

I need to display this custom image on Product Page at Footer.

I have used Below code in phtml file to print image.

```
<?php
        $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
        $_product = $block->getProduct();

        $productImageAttr = $_product->getCustomAttribute( 'product_image_custom_1' );
        $productImage = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
            ->init($_product, 'product_image_custom_1')
            ->setImageFile($productImageAttr->getValue());
?>
        <img src="<?php echo $productImage->getUrl() ?>" alt="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($productImage->getLabel()) ?>" />
```

it prints image Fine, But Image label in Alt not display.
it prints Product Name.

how to print alt text attribute in frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code

```
$productImageAttr = $_product->getCustomAttribute( 'product_image_custom_1' );
$productImage = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
    ->init($_product, 'product_image_custom_1')
    ->setImageFile($productImageAttr->getValue());
$mediaGallery = $_product->getData('media_gallery');
foreach($mediaGallery['images'] as $imagesCode)
{
    if($imagesCode['file'] == $productImageAttr->getValue())
    {
        echo $imagesCode['label'];  
    }
}
```